# Django: Create a custom order of objects in django model

Tags: python, django, web-applications, backend

I'm trying to build a teaching website of sorts in Django. I have a model called Test:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test_directions = models.TextField(null=True)

    test_status_new = models.ManyToManyField('StudentProfile', related_name='test_status_new')
    test_status_good = models.ManyToManyField('StudentProfile', related_name='test_status_good')

    test_status_repeat = models.ManyToManyField('StudentProfile', related_name='test_status_repeat')
    test_repeat_due = models.IntegerField(default=6)

    test_status_due = models.ManyToManyField('StudentProfile', related_name='test_status_due')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.test_name}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<{self.test_name}>"
```

I'd like to give them a custom ordering somehow. I am displaying them in a table like so: [image] and would like to change the order of each individual tests from the two buttons in the Order column.

If I click Up, the test moves one row up. If I click down, the test moves down one row. How would I implement something like this?

Comment: It depends, should it persist even after user changes of page or is it just for current display ? Should it affect other users or each user can have its own order ? The thing is that the answer can go from pure html/js or more complex architecture on the backend involving M2M/FK relationships...

Comment: @BriseBalloches I'd like to save the new order that the user selects. I guess that would involve more backend work...

Comment: As simple solution in django would be to add a sort of index to the object in Django models and write a function to change that index whenever this button is pressed. but this quickly becomes a problem if you have a lot of data in the database